# Set persistent cookies in PHP

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am using codeigniter framework.
This is my currenct code to set cookies in browser. If there is a known IP address then it won't ask you to enter security answer. o.w. user needs to enter security answer.

Everything is working fine, except when I close the broswer entirely or restart my PC, cookies get deleted and it asks me again to enter that information.

**CODE**

```
$ip_address = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$ip_cookie = array('name'=>'ip',
                   'value'=>$ip_address,
                   'expire' => time() + (10 * 365 * 24 * 60 * 60)
                   );
set_cookie($ip_cookie);
```

As you can see I also setup expire time for this.

Comment: Check out the CodeIgniter cookie helper:  https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/cookie_helper.html

Comment: I checked it already. I found only one thing that you need to specify expire time. That I ready mentioned in my code.

Comment: make sure your browser isn't configured to delete cookies on close

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Might not be the cause but you are setting an expiration date in 54 years or so. From [the manual](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/input.html):

> The expiration is set in seconds, which will be added to the current
>   time. **Do not include the time, but rather only the number of seconds
>   from now that you wish the cookie to be valid.** If the expiration is
>   set to zero the cookie will only last as long as the browser is open.

Perhaps the browser has an upper limit for expiration time. You should also check your browser developer tools for actual values received.

Comment: So, you want me to remove `time()` from expire?

Comment: Since the manual says you have to do so in order to obtain a valid cookie, it's an interesting course of action...

Comment: As soon as time is concern, I used `time()+60*60*24*30` in regular password cookies. And same thing happens with this too. It asks for password again.

Comment: So you are doing in two places what the manual warns against and none of them work?

Comment: I have removed `time()` from both cookies. And it works fine. Can you explain, why `time()` cause problem in expire ?

Comment: I don't know: either the CodeIgniter algorithm discards dates too far in the future or your browser ignores expiration dates in 2068 as blatant abuse. But I wonder if you're aware yet that CodeIgniter expects a number of seconds from now and not a Unix timestamp?